# When I will see my self assessment paid tax on FORM 26AS

Tags: income-tax, india

Today, I have paid my payable amount of income tax through [Government Website](https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp) as Self Assessment Tax using Chalan 280.

Now, I want to file my ITR but same tax paid amount is not available in FORM 26AS.

I am getting pop-up message on TDS sheet that "Please verify the Tax Payment Details as available in your form 26AS"

**How to update FORM 26AS if I have paid my income tax through Government website?**

I want to file my ITR.**Is it fine if I file my ITR even my payment details are not reflected in form 26AS?**

Answer (score 2):

> Now, I want to file my ITR but same tax paid amount is not available in FORM 26AS.

If the Form 26AS was provided by your employer before you paid this, it will not be reflected.

> How to update FORM 26AS if I have paid my income tax through Government website?

You can download/view the [Trace form 26AS here](https://nriservices.tdscpc.gov.in/nriapp/login.xhtml).

> Is it fine if I file my ITR even my payment details are not reflected in form 26AS?

Yes it is fine. **Ensure** that while filing the returns in the Self Assessment / Advance Tax section, you fill out the details of tax paid; i.e. BSR code Amount and other details that you would have on the receipt of the Self Assessment tax paid.